# Conditional: if + past simple, future simple

Tags: conditionals, future, simple-past

I know that that there are conditionals to speculate about permanent state or situations which had a result in the past.
Is there a conditional: if + past simple, subject + will + verb.
For talking something that maybe happened, and if it happened, something else will happen.

Examples:

If you studied, you will get a good mark.

If you were tired of the old crosshair, I-Beam, arrow cursor choices, you'll love the new selections.

are those two senteces correct? is correct writing conditional sentences in this way? because I have never seen on internet sentences like those (if + past simple, subject + will + verb)

Comment: What is your question? The meaning seems abundantly clear.

Comment: "If you studied, you will get a good mark" could only be said after the examination (or perhaps just before, when no more study is possible), but before the results have come out. In your second example, it would be more natural to say "If you _are_ tired of...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are fine.

The only rule governing time reference (which is not the same thing as morphological tense) in conditionals is that in **actualization** conditionals (*If P happens, then Q happens*), the sentence must be parseable as Q occurring after P. In **inference** conditionals (*If P is true, then Q is true*), there is no such rule.